# Multiple Automatically Renewable Subscriptions not showing

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, skproduct

I am trying to integrate multiple "Automatically Renewable Subscriptions" in my app, but i am getting only one of the SKProducts. Is there any limitation from Apple over multiple "Automatically Renewable Subscriptions"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it done - i was passing a single productIdentifier to SKProductRequest set. Passing the whole set of productIdentifiers i defined in iTunes fixed the problem.

```
NSSet *inAppProductsSet = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"iap.prod1",
                           @"iap.prod2",
                           @"iap.prod3", nil];
SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:inAppProductsSet];
```